# Forcing boundary conditions in interpolated/kriged data?

Tags: python, interpolation, kriging

I am using `pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging` to generate a spatially continuous field from sparse point data (see image below). The data (glacier ice thickness) are such that there is a hard boundary (red line, glacier margin) at which a specified value must be met (0 ice thickness). I delineated the glacier margin (a portion of these are connected by red lines in the image below) and wrote 0 ice thickness into the input dataset at each of those points.

[image: Ice thickness data (point) and kriged result (raster)]

I then run `OK = OrdinaryKriging(eToget, nToget, hToget, variogram_model="linear", verbose=False, enable_plotting=False, )` (where 'Toget' suffixes indicate the data have been combined with the boundary values)  and `z, ss = OK.execute("grid", vec_x, vec_y)` to produce the output above.

As you can see, the kriging varies too smoothly, and produces non-zero values outside of the glacier margin, which is physically unacceptable.

**Is there a way to force the kriging method (or some other spatial interpolation method) to match boundary values, such that everything outside the red lines would have a value of zero?**

I know I could do this by masking/clipping the output, but there would be a non-physical discontinuity at the glacier margin if I did that, so I am looking for a way to produce smooth & continuous data up to the boundary, but are forced to match the boundary value.

I feel like this must be a relatively common issue (e.g., interpolating lake bathymetry, where 0 depth must be met along the lake boundaries), but I haven't been able to track down useful information in googling.